# how can perror and errno show different results (Linux)?

Tags: linux, errno

I am calling bind() on a socket, and the call is failing owing to "Address in use". I am fairly confident that's the failure, anyway - the socket has been left open by a previous instance of the app that crashed. Specifically, bind() returns a negative value. However, errno reads zero on the function's return. Bizarrely, perror(), however, generates "Address in use".

Under what conditions can errno and perror() disagree on the value of the error code? I understand that the errno system is thread-safe (there are other threads running in the meantime). I am on Linux 3.14.43.

```
if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    printf("\nerrno %i %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    perror("PERROR");

    //  raise error
    __ERROR("failed bind socket");
}
```

The above code generates this output:

```
errno 0 Success
PERROR: Address already in use
**** ERROR **** failed bind socket
```

Perhaps I have misunderstood the relationship between errno, strerror(), and perror()?

Comment: My guess is that your `errno` is different than perror's `errno`.  Are you declaring your own variable called `errno` in a file?

Comment: No, I've just been through a grep to confirm that. Though, it does suggest that there are two symbols, doesn't it? Could I be making a linking error of some sort and accidentally linking the symbol twice, I wonder...

Comment: Try running `nm your_program | grep errno` and see what comes up.  `nm` will list all the symbols in your program.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already. All I get is one symbol, "U __errno_location", which is singular at least I guess. I wondered if the executable is linking with multiple libs that have their own errno def? Is there a way to do a sort of recursive nm?

Comment: 1 - `errno`, `strerror()`, and `perror()` are all implemented in libc - please edit the question to add the libc version. 2 - I'm unable to reproduce this on my box (libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu10).

Comment: 3 - glibc generally defines `errno` as a macro. 4 - general error handling note: `strerror()` could alter `errno`.